# How to turn non valid variable name into a valid one?

Tags: javascript, variables

I get some data from the server with variables that are not valid in Javascript.

Example : `Short_%`

Is there a way to turn it into a valid one ?

Also, related question : how do I call such a variable name ?
THis : `myObject.Short_%` won't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? There isn't a way to "redefine" what a valid variable name is in javascript.

Comment: you can refer to myObject['Short_%'] though. it doesn't make it a valid variable name but a property name is just a string.

Comment: you can iterate by object's keys and rename keys whichever way you want

Comment: @nthnchu : I was thinking there may be a way to use unicode or something to make the variable name valid. I'm defining types for my data which I get from the server

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `Short_%` as name, the difference is how to access this value. Use the square bracket syntax to set/get a value:

```
var myvalue=myObject['Short_%'];
```

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, ***any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier*** (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) ***can only be accessed using the square bracket notation***. This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties